# Rotate Camera vector to look at player Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, camera

I create a game, like minigolf/pool. I want to have a camera which follow player.

Position is normally ok, I get the ball direction and I lerp.
Rotation is almost ok. Currently, rotation by Y axis is ok, but camera look straigth forward, and don't look down to the player : 
[image]

[image]

I already try many thing , quaternion angleToaxis, quarternion lookat ... but doesn't look good, the camera go look away ...
Here my code

```c#
namespace CameraManagerNameSpace
{
    public class CameraManager : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        public float cameraHeight=13f;
        public PlayerNameSpace.Player playerToFollow; 
        public float followSpeed = 3f;
        public float rotationSpeed = 1f;

        float distance;
        Vector3 position;
        Vector3 newPos;
        Quaternion rotation;
        Quaternion newRot;
        Vector3 playerPrevPos, playerMoveDir;
        bool firstMoveDone=false;

        void Start() 
        {
            playerPrevPos = playerToFollow.player_transform.position;
            distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,playerToFollow.player_transform.position);
        }

        void FixedUpdate() 
        {
            if(Vector3.Distance(playerToFollow.player_transform.position ,playerPrevPos)>0.5f || firstMoveDone)
            {
                playerMoveDir = playerToFollow.player_transform.position - playerPrevPos;
                firstMoveDone = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                playerMoveDir = new Vector3(0,0,0);
            }

            if (playerMoveDir != Vector3.zero)
            {
                playerMoveDir.Normalize();

                newPos = playerToFollow.player_transform.position - playerMoveDir * distance;
                newRot =Quaternion.LookRotation(playerMoveDir,Vector3.up);

                position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(newPos.x,newPos.y+cameraHeight,newPos.z), followSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, newRot, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

                transform.position = position;
                transform.rotation = rotation;

                playerPrevPos = playerToFollow.player_transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I don't know why, but after the balls stop the camera continue to do some movement very jerky, jolting, halting.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's to blame for the problem because you're using `Lerp` methods incorrectly. You should use `Vector3.MoveTowards` and `Quaternion.RotateTowards`:
                `position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(newPos.x,newPos.y+cameraHeight,newPos.z), followSpeed * Time.deltaTime);`
                `rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, newRot, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);` (your `rotationSpeed` and `followSpeed` should also be higher)

Comment: Is there also a reason why you are using `FixedUpdate`? You should rather use `Update` since `FixedUpdate` is only used for physics related stuff.

Comment: @Ruzihm the problem is: The nice smoothing will be gone .. the reason most people (ab)use `Lerp` in the first place

Comment: I also noted you are setting the rotation to look into the direction the player moves .. why do you expect it to look at the player then?

Comment: @derHugo using `MoveTowards(a,b,Time.deltaTime*speed)` and `RotationTowards(a,b,Time.deltaTime*speed)` gets the smoothing... I'm mostly saying it's hard to know if the problem is due to the 3rd argument going outside [0,1] unexpectedly, but I think you might have found the problem with your most recent comment :)

Comment: @Ruzihm nope .. sorry I didn't word that well ... they use `Lerp` because the "smooth" ease-out effect (movement gets slower at the end)

Comment: @derHugo ah I see :)

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks for your comment, Indeed I need some ease in out effect. If you have some better idea, please share :D .

Comment: @LexaGC In that case, try something like `float easeFactor = 0.5f;` `Vector3 destPos = new Vector3(newPos.x,newPos.y+cameraHeight,newPos.z);` `position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destPos, Time.deltaTime * Mathf.Min(followSpeed, (destPos-transform.position).magnitude*easeFactor + 0.05));` and  `float rotAngle = Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, newRot);` `rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, newRot, Time.deltaTime * Mathf.Min(rotationSpeed, rotAngle * easeFactor + 0.05));` This way, you are guaranteed to eventually reach the goal despite any rounding errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in

```c#
newRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerMoveDir,Vector3.up);
```

you are saying the camera to look in the same direction the player is moving ... not to look at the player. This would work if you wouldn't give the camera an extra position offset in the `Y` axis.

---

You might want to rather try

```c#
// vector pointing from the camera towards the player
var targetDirection = playerToFollow.player_transform.position - transform.position;
newRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection, Vector3.up);
```

---

You should also rather use `Update` since [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) is only used for physics related stuff (also see [Update & FixedUpdate](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate))

Comment: Hi @derHugo , Thanks for answer my issu. 
In fact, I alreay have an offset call "cameraHeight" in my position 
`position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(newPos.x,newPos.y+cameraHeight,newPos.z), followSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, newRot, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
`

Comment: You're completly right for fixUpdate/update, but I don't think It will change everything. Indeed I will change it to update.

Comment: @LexaGC yes as said .. this offset is the problem why your solution is not working ... I showed you what to use instead ;)

Comment: Yes, but I want this position of the camera. I don't want the camera to be just at the same Y axis value as the player but higher and look down. 
Anyway I will test it, I come back to you just after :D

Comment: Lol this is not what I am suggesting ... Use your position at it is .. only change the rotation to my suggestion ;)

Comment: Here you kidding me it work great ... How could it be possible, I'm pretty sure I test this solution before ... XD anyway it work.
Pretty logical considering what should done LookRotation

Comment: As said the difference is that you used the players moving direction .. which is different to the direction Camera->Player :)